# Wired connection detected but no internet access

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ethernet, 21.04

I can confirm this question has been asked several times,unfortunately none of the solutions worked in my case.

I can confirm the ethernet cable works fine. I just unplug it from nearby computer running 18.04 and connect to this new computer. If I replace the cable on the old computer, everything work fine. This new computer shows wired connection detected, but I cannot access the Internet.
[image]

[image]

But then:

```
$ ifconfig
enp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 2001:690:2200:9aa1:7055:cd5f:6e9d:7072  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2001:690:2200:9aa1:5159:6a43:60c:8217  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::d530:de7:90c9:7c8e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 4c:cc:6a:91:41:d5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 126869  bytes 84840453 (84.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 24876  bytes 4529725 (4.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 15848  bytes 4739907 (4.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15848  bytes 4739907 (4.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 

$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 15
       serial: 4c:cc:6a:91:41:d5
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-40-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:df004000-df004fff memory:df000000-df003fff


$ ping 8.8.8.8
ping: connect: Network is unreachable

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:    21.04
Codename:   hirsute
```

What other thing do you suggest?

**EDIT**

The ethernet cable works fine when transferred to the old computer, but not when plugged to this new machine.

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
cat: /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory
 
$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: You're not getting an IPV4 address. Did this work before? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Do you have Access Control enabled in your router? Please describe your wiring from the computer port all the way to the router/modem. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema question edited to show the output. Them same cable is working fine on the computer I want to replace due to storage shortage (running ubuntu `18.04`). Is it possible to have the ethernet configured only to specific MAC address?

Comment: Show me a screenshot of the IPv4 tab in your wired connection settings. Also, please do describe your wiring as per my previous request. And also the Access Control part...

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518266/ping-displays-name-or-service-not-known this helped me fix the issue, hope this helps! I have basically zero programming experience, had to look up how to save and edit files in nano also, other than that really straightforward.